# Nextjs 13 mix server component inside client component

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm really confused with nextjs 13, I want the page.tsx keep as Server Component, but I have Create button on the top and Edit button in each element of data, but because I need state to toggle the modal, so it force me to make it as client component, I can Wrap Button and Modal as separate client component, but I want to use the same Modal when edit the data, And I want the static component still rendered from server, so when initial render it return full of content, the layout, the Buttons, the PageTitle

page.tsx

```js
export default async function Users() {
   const users = await getUsers();
   
   // this part only allowed in client component
   const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
   const [title, setTitle] = useState("New"); // or "Edit"
   const [id, setId] = useState(0);
   const onSave = (data, id = null) => {
       // perform create or update
       if (id) {
         onUpdate(id);
       } else {
         onCreate();
       }
   }

   const onEdit(id) {
      setShow(true);
      setId(id);
      setTitle("Edit");
   }

   return (
    <>
      <div>
         // I want this part rendered in server, 
         // in real layout it nested more deep with static content
        <PageTitle title="Users" subtitle="All user member"/>
        <Button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>
          Create
        </Button>
      </div>
      {users && (
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading users...</p>}>
          <UserList users={users} onEdit={onEdit} />
        </Suspense>
      )}
      <ModalUserForm show={show} title={title} onSave={onSave} id={id} />
    </>
  );
}
```

UserList.tsx

```js
"use client"
export const UserList = ({users, onEdit}) {
   return users.map(user => {
      return (
         <p>{user.name}</p>
         <Button variant={"success"} onClick={() => onEdit(user.id)}>
             Edit
         </Button>
      )
   });
}
```